# WinForms: Adding custom ToolStripMenuItem to MenuStrip in designer

Tags: c#, winforms

In Windows Forms If I make a custom control that inherits from `ToolStripMenuItem` is there a way to add this `CustomToolStripMenuItem` to `MenuStrip` from designer or do I have to do it through code? (since the `ToolStripMenuItem` are added without dragging them from the toolbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decorating it with this attribute:

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip)]
public class MyToolStrip : ToolStripMenuItem {

}
```